# Error message keeps appearing when cloning android studio project

Tags: android, android-studio

So, I'm currently working on two ideas that hit me simultaneously.

I managed to get quite a ways in the one project, and decided to copy it as a starting point for my other project. The only problem is that when I tried to copy the project and rename the package name / applicationID, I was hit with an error.

As such, I tried to make a new project and copy the files over individually, renaming the package manually in each of the files. I'm still getting error messages. The exact error message I'm getting is

> Installation failed with message Invalid File: C:\Users\Owner\AndroidStudioProjects\App3-test1\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_6.apk.
>   It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.
>
> WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!
>
> Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

Now, I'm still a novice, but I'm assuming it's saying that the copied app won't run unless I uninstall the original.

Is that the case? How can I clone the project in such a way that I can get both to be installed on the same phone?

P.S. I'm not sure if it's relevant, but I'm testing on a Nexus 5x.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Rename Package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package)

Answer (score 0):

Don't copy the whole project. Just create a new one with a different package name. Don't copy everything, just the classes, xml's and drawables. then copy just a portion of your AndroidManifest.xml file like uses-permission and activity. Do not use previous package name manifest. Do the same thing in build.gradle file. just copy your dependencies. hope it helps

Comment: I don't know what you did but I do the same thing and I did not encounter any error.